# How to make a line in interactive map leaflet using json file data

Tags: javascript

I have data which is the coordinates point json file ("point.json")

:

```
{          
    "Latitude": "-10.0",
    "Longitude": "122.7",
},
{
    "Latitude": "-10.6",
    "Longitude": "122.5",
},
{
    "Latitude": "-11.0",
    "Longitude": "121.7",   
},
```

how can I make a connecting line based on latitude and longitude coordinates in the order from top to bottom in the interactive map leaflet

I have used this method but it doesn't work

```
var jsonData = 'point.json';
            function getJSONValue(fileJSON) {
                var value = $.ajax({
                    url: fileJSON,
                    async: false
                }).responseText;
                return value
            }

 hotspotData = getJSONValue(jsonData)
            var hotspotDataJSON = JSON.parse(hotspotData)
```

after I get the data from the json file

then I want to make the points connect using lines :

```
for (i = 0; i < hotspotDataJSON.length; i++) {
var Coordinate = new L.latLng(([hotspotDataJSON[i].Latitude, hotspotDataJSON[i].Longitude]))
 var polyline = L.polyline(Coordinate, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
 // zoom the map to the polyline
 map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
```

That way it doesn't work, is there anyone who can help me in completing this job?
make a line from the points in the json data

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: yes, not working. . for line point to point not show on the map

Comment: `L.Polyline` needs two pairs of `[lat, lng]`, not one.

Comment: Can You help me? @Daantje Because it takes data from outside the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`L.Polyline` needs two pairs of coordinates to parse a line between the two points. You could do something like this;

```
for (i = 0; i < hotspotDataJSON.length - 1; i++) {
                var Coordinate = new L.latLng(([hotspotDataJSON[i].Latitude, hotspotDataJSON[i].Longitude]))
                var CoordinateB = new L.latLng(([hotspotDataJSON[i + 1].Latitude, hotspotDataJSON[i + 1].Longitude]))
                var polyline = L.polyline([Coordinate, CoordinateB], {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
            // zoom the map to the polyline
                map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
```

Here is a running example; http://embed.plnkr.co/2XSeS1/

Comment: success brother . . .

Comment: No problem, glad to help ;)